# Set multiple attributes on root elemement using web.config transformation

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config, web-deployment, web-config-transform

In visual studio (web.config transformations) I have a transformation I want to perform which adds two attributes on the root element. 
One attrbute works (but not multiple ones).
And I can set multiple attributes on a child element.
I have tried SetAttributes with and without specifying the names of the attributes, no luck.

Ideas??

**example**

```
    <element xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" attrOne="One" attrTwo="Two">
      <children>
       <child name="One" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" attrOne="One" attrTwo="Two" />
      </children>
    </element>
```

**desired effect**

```
    <element attrOne="One" attrTwo="Two">
      <children>
       <child name="One" attrOne="One" attrTwo="Two" />
      </children>
    </element>
```

The "element" section is really a custom section of the web.config file...like so:

```
<configuration>

... <element configSource="App_Data\element.config" />
```

this transformation is meant to be used on the element.config file (using slow cheetah)

**Update**
This apparently doesn't work either:

```
<element xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xdt:Transform="Replace" attrOne="One" attrTwo="Two">
  <children>
   <child name="One" attrOne="One" attrTwo="Two" />
  </children>
</element>
```

But this does:

```
<element xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xdt:Transform="Replace" attrOne="One">
  <children>
   <child name="One" attrOne="One" attrTwo="Two" />
  </children>
</element>
```

As soon as there are more than 1 attribute on the root element it fails

Answer (score 17):

Have you tried a document transform like this that sets multiple attributes at the same time by passing a list of attributes to set to `SetAttribute()`?

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx) form more info.

Specifically: *Transform="SetAttributes(comma-delimited list of one or more attribute names)"*

```
<element xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(attrOne,attrTwo)" attrOne="One" attrTwo="Two">
  <children>
   <child name="One" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(attrOne,attrTwo)" attrOne="One" attrTwo="Two" />
  </children>
</element>
```

Answer (score 0):

The document element of a `web.config` file is `<configuration>`. In your example, `<element>` is probably a child of `<configuration>`. Try:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <element xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" attrOne="One" attrTwo="Two">
        <children>
            <child xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" name="One"
                   attrOne="One" attrTwo="Two" />
        </children>
    </element>
</configuration>
```

Comment: sorry, meant to say that it is not the web.config file it self but this shows a custom section of it. It is however interesting that SetAttributes works with one attribute but not with two...on the root element